# Как одновременно присвоить класс двум элементам через ForEach?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery, css3

При добавлении класса `.active` к `price` через метод forEach не получается добавить класс и к другому элементу `added`, чтобы было одновременное присвоение класса `.active` к двум элементам. Тоже самое и с удалением класса `.active` при клике на элемент `added`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  const price = document.querySelectorAll('.item-card__price'),
    added = document.querySelectorAll('.item-card__added');

  price.forEach(item => {
    item.addEventListener('click', () => {
      item.classList.add('active')
      added.classList.add('active')
    });
  });

  added.forEach(item => {
    item.addEventListener('click', () => {
      price.classList.remove('active')
      item.classList.remove('active')
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item-card__top">
  <div class="item-card__price">2.75 $</div>
  <div class="item-card__added">Added!</div>
</div>
```

При добавлении класса `.active` к элементу `price` он должен сдвигаться вправо, теряя прозрачность, а `added` с классом `.active` по аналогии сдвигаться одновременно влево, получая видимость.

Comment: Что-то мне подсказывает, что Вы забыли поставить точку с запятой после каждого добавления/удаления класса в EventListener...

Comment: @4500zenja в js так можно писать

Comment: нужен воспроизводимый пример. без html и сниппета и [минимального, самодостаточного и воспроизводимого примера](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) тут разговаривать не о чем

Comment: а, хотя, кажется вижу в чём причина

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как я понял, верстка у вас примерно такая и нужно вам примерно следующее:

```js
const cards = document.querySelectorAll('.item-card');

cards.forEach(card => {
  let price = card.querySelector('.item-card__price');
  let add = card.querySelector('.item-card__added');

  price.addEventListener('click', () => {
    price.classList.add('active');
    add.classList.add('active');
  });

  add.addEventListener('click', () => {
    price.classList.remove('active');
    add.classList.remove('active');
  });
});
```

```css
.item-card {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.item-card>div {
  margin-bottom: 3px;
}

.item-card .active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="item-card">
  <div class="item-card__price">$100</div>
  <div class="item-card__added">Add</div>
</div>

<div class="item-card">
  <div class="item-card__price">$200</div>
  <div class="item-card__added">Add</div>
</div>

<div class="item-card">
  <div class="item-card__price">$300</div>
  <div class="item-card__added">Add</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо всем, разобрался!

Answer (score 0):

`price` и `added` (кстати правильно писать во множественном числе: price**s**, раз уж это **коллекция**) - это коллекции. Собственно вот и вся проблема. Вот тут:

```
added.classList.add('active')
```

идёт попытка добавить класс в коллекцию, а не в каждый элемент коллекции (нужен цикл, либо, возможно, какой-то селектор для указания конкретного элемента с таким классом внутри конкретного блока...зависит от цели)

аналогично здесь:

```
price.classList.remove('active')
```

идёт попытка добавить класс в коллекцию, а не в каждый элемент коллекции (нужен цикл, либо, возможно, какой-то селектор для указания конкретного элемента с таким классом внутри конкретного блока...зависит от цели)